# How to extract data from SQL Server XML with namespaces?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I can use the SQL Server XML methods node() and values() to extract data from XML but it does not work when the XML contains name spaces

In the example below, my first XML behaves properly (ID = 1) while I can't get anything back from the second one (ID = 2)...

```
CREATE TABLE EricXml(ID INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), MyXml XML);

INSERT INTO EricXml(MyXML) VALUES(
'<Calculation CalculationName="Calc2" >
  <TargetTable SchemaName="schema2" TableName="Table1">tut</TargetTable>
  <TargetTable SchemaName="schema1" TableName="Table2" >pouet</TargetTable>
</Calculation>')

INSERT INTO EricXml(MyXML) VALUES(
'<Calculation  xmlns="http://bluebayinvest.com/CalculationRules.xsd" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    CalculationName="Calc3" >
  <TargetTable SchemaName="schema1" TableName="Table3" />
</Calculation>')

SELECT ID, MyXml
        , X.N.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
        , X.N.value('./@SchemaName', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS SchemaName
    FROM EricXml
    CROSS APPLY MyXML.nodes('/Calculation/TargetTable') AS X(N)
```

My result comes entirely from the first row...

[image]

Any idea what I should do to retrieve XML extract from the second row?